# Properties applying to children although using direct descendant selector ">"

Tags: css

I am using `.class > ul > li`.

Basically I would like to know why there are some properties that work as expected (like `border`) but others as `text-transform`, `color` or `font-size` affect the list inside the list.

Here's an example: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ece2z0n2/)**

I find really annoying the need to use `.class ul li ul li` to "undo" the text style that I want just on the first direct `<li>` child.

Any links with docs that would allow me to learn how this selector really works will be greatly apreciated.

Comment: The properties you're using (besides border) are all inheritable.

Comment: Here's a workaround: http://jsfiddle.net/ece2z0n2/1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour it is called **inheritance**.
Some css properties are inherited from their parent whereas other aren't.

### Inheritance

> When no value for an inherited property has been specified on an
>   element, the element gets the computed value of that property on its
>   parent element. Only the root element of the document gets the initial
>   value given in the property's summary. [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance)]

### List of inherited properties

```
azimuth             border-collapse    border-spacing        caption-side
color               cursor             direction             elevation
empty-cells         font-family        font-size             font-style
font-variant        font-weight        font                  letter-spacing
line-height         list-style-image   list-style-position   list-style-type
list-style          orphans            pitch-range           pitch
quotes              richness           speak-header          speak-numeral
speak-punctuation   speak              speech-rate           stress
text-align          text-indent        text-transform        visibility
voice-family        volume             white-space           widows
word-spacing
```

*Extracted from [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) on 17/03/15*

---

### The `all` property

This property allows to control *CSS* inheritance with the `initial | inherit | unset` values :

> The CSS *all* shorthand property resets all properties, apart from
>   unicode-bidi and direction, to their initial or inherited value. [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all)]

This property currently has the status of "Candidate Recommendation" but the [major modern borwsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all#Browser_compatibility) (except safari) have implemented it.

---

### For your example case :

The `border` property doesn't inherit so the child elements won't have a border event though the parent does.

But `font-size`, `color` and `text-transform` are properties that inherit to the child elements. Therefore the second level list item has the same `font-size`, `color` and `text-transform` as it's parent.

**Conclusion :**
The selector you are using is correct and targets only the first level list items but some properties like `color` are inherited to the second level list items.

Comment: Yep, to back this up, simply adding `li { color: green; }` will make those other `li` elements have a green foreground.

Comment: Ty. I guess I have to get use to add on my css sheets some previous instructions (as in a reset sheet) like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ece2z0n2/4/ not the most optimal solution but good enough. Any chance you have a link with a whole list of css proprties that are by default inherit? (can't seem to find any but I will keep looking). any ty,  apreciate your time

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez couldn't find a better list than the table on W3.org, sorry. And your solution seems the way to go until [`all: initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all) has better browser support.

Comment: @web-tiki can you also suggest a workaround please? I'm very interested in this question.

Comment: @sdcr I am not aware of another way than hardcoding the inherited properties as Alvaro Menéndez did in his last comment. The `all: initial ` ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/all)) property will allow to prevent inheritance but it currently has pretty low browser support.

Comment: @web-tiki thanks for pointing it out, that is super powerful property, good to know.

Comment: @AlvaroMenéndez I have extracted a list of inherited properties form the w3.org reference table and edited it in the answer.

Comment: Fantastic, Thank You very much. I will start right now a kind of reset css sheet, that I'm sure I'll include on many future projects, to cancel all inherit properties. at least till all:initial get's better support.

Answer (score 1):

As you did not define style for your inner `ul` will have the same style as its parent.

What you have to do is wrap the text in a span

```
<div class="menu ">
  <ul>
    <li><span>This is uppercase red</span>
        <ul>
            <li>this should not be uppercase or red</li>
            <li>this should not be uppercase or red</li>
            <li>this should not be uppercase or red</li>                
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And apply your css definition  to `.menu>ul>li>span`

Comment: The `span` element is unnecessary.

Comment: hmmm... it is necessary to answer the question (precisely the part where op finds annoying to "undo" previous definitions)... but if you can tell more about it, do not hesitate ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML nesting isn't correct and therefore it considers the entire ul inside li as content of that li. Try this:

```
<div class="menu ">
    <ul>
        <li>This is uppercase red</li>
        <ul>
            <li>this should not be uppercase or red</li>
            <li>this should not be uppercase or red</li>
            <li>this should not be uppercase or red</li>                
        </ul>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no, you're putting an ul directly under another ul, which isn't right.

Comment: ok with @sdcr you can't nest an `ul` directly inside another `ul`. `ul` elements only accept `li` elements as children

Comment: @adam thought so too but according to W3C this is also valid.

Comment: @SCHTAILian don't think so, on MDN it says "Permitted content zero or more <li> elements, eventually mixed with <ol> and <ul> elements." I actually made a test over the validator and it says "Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context."

Comment: @sdcr  and adam indeed was looking in the wrong place, my bad.

Comment: @SCHTAILian no problems :) it's just a very interesting topic that i haven't seen for quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the .menu>ul>li.
And it's correct, but there is a ul inside the .menu>ul>li.

So the target + the children will be affected by the property.

Consider this HTML:

```
<body>
 <h1>Example</h1>
 <div class="sub">test</div>
</body>
```

And this CSS :

```
   body
   {
    font-family:calibri;
   }
```

Here, both h1 and div.sub will be in calibri font.